# How to make a 90 degree rotation happen over time

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, quaternion

I'm trying to take a RotateAround function and make it happen over time. I've been tinkering with Quaternions to try and get it to work but I can't quite figure it out.

This is the code:

```
public class RotateCamera : MonoBehaviour {

public Vector3 rotatePoint = new Vector3(0,0,5);

public void RotateLeft ()
{
    transform.RotateAround (rotatePoint, Vector3.up, 90);
}

public void RotateRight ()
{
    transform.RotateAround (rotatePoint, Vector3.up, -90);
}
```

I'm applying each void to a button, and this works like a Final Fantasy Tactics camera - rotate an isometric camera 90 degrees. But it happens instantly, and I want to make it happen over time, like a second or a half a second. I'm super new to programming and I can't find any guides on this or any other posts using google, so I'm asking on here as a last resort. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

There would be numerous ways to implement this effect, because there are many ways to do timed transitions and rotations.

The general steps to take could be something like this

- Store `start_time = now`
- Store `start_rotation = x`
- Calculate `end_time = now + 60`
- Calculate `end_rotation = y`

Now at any time you can calculate a linear parameter `p = (time - start_time) / (start_time - end_time)`. If `time` is between `start_time` and `end_time` then `p` will be between 0 and 1.

This allows us now to do linear interpolation of any value, for example the rotation value. You can choose to do linear interpolation on the Euler angle,

```
start_rotation = 90
end_rotation = -90
r = start_rotation + p * (end_rotation - start_rotation)   
transform = initial_transform
current_rotation = transform.Rotate(0, -45, r)
```

uusing `RotateAround` from a default position,

```
start_rotation = 90
end_rotation = -90
r = start_rotation + p * (end_rotation - start_rotation)   
transform = initial_transform
current_rotation = transform.RotateAround(rotatePoint, Vector3.up, r)
```

or using quaternions

```
current_rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(start_rotation, end_rotation, p)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to kick off an action that will play out over several frames, a Coroutine is often a convenient way to do this. Here's one way to use a Coroutine for this purpose:

```
public Vector3 rotatePoint = new Vector3(0,0,5);
public float rotationSpeed = 90f;

Quaternion _targetRotation;
Vector3 _localOffset;
Coroutine _rotationCoroutine;

public void Start() {
    // Remember where the center of rotation should be in our local space.
    _localOffset = transform.InverseTransformPoint(rotatePoint);
    _targetRotation = transform.rotation;
}

public void RotateLeft () { Rotate(90); }

public void RotateRight () { Rotate(-90); }

void Rotate(float increment) {    
    // Spin our target rotation in the desired direction.
    _targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, increment, 0) * _targetRotation;

    // If we're not already rotating, start a new rotation.
    // (Otherwise, the coroutine will automatically handle the new target)
    if(_rotationCoroutine == null)
        _rotationCoroutine = StartCoroutine(RotationCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator RotationCoroutine() {
    // Until our current rotation aligns with the target...
    while(Quaternion.Dot(transform.rotation, _targetRotation) < 1f) {
        // Rotate at a consistent speed toward the target.
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
            transform.rotation,
            _targetRotation,
            rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime
        );

        // Adjust our position to preserve the relationship to the pivot.
        Vector3 offset = transform.TransformPoint(_localOffset);
        transform.position = rotatePoint - offset;

        // Wait a frame, then resume.
        yield return null;
    }

    // Clear the coroutine so the next input starts a fresh one.
    _rotationCoroutine = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector rotate your camera to the desired position and enter those values in the script area. Click left and right arrows on your keyboard, and adjust the time.

```
public class RorateCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 rightRotation;
    public Vector3 leftRotation;
    public float speed = 0.1F;

    private bool rotateRight;

    public void RotateLeft()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(leftRotation), Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }

    public void RotateRight()
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(rightRotation), Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            rotateRight = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            rotateRight = true;
        }

        if (rotateRight)
        {
            RotateRight();
        }
        else
        {
            RotateLeft();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I do the RotateAround function, the camera's position also changes. Won't these functions just change the rotation of the camera? I'm probably missing something, but I'm assuming where transform.rotation is, I would type something like (0,90,0) - to turn the camera 90 degrees clockwise?


Just for reference, I checked all the angles and positions the camera would have:
South: position = (1, 5, -5), angle = (35, 0, 0)
West: position = (-12, 5, 8), angle = (35, 90, 0)
North: position = (1, 5, 21), angle = (35, -180, 0)
East: position = (14, 5, 8), angle = (35, -90, 0)

Comment: They will rotate the camera over a period of time and NOT snap instantly. You need to adjust the Speed variable. As you increase the Speed the camera will take longer to rotate.